# is any way using postgresql as file transferrer

Tags: postgresql

I'm preparing my project database. I need to save employee's photos. My sql server is on the network. I want to upload image from client computer to server for example C:\images directory (not to table) by using c# code or query. Is it possible? Is there anyone have done such thing?
Thank u for your help.

Comment: Using C# code?  Sure.  Share the code you've written so far, and explain what doesn't work.  SO is for helping you with your own code, not for writing it for you.

Comment: I used C# code just for getting path of image on client computer. After getting that path I WANT POSTGRESQL TO COPY THAT IMAGE TO SQL SERVER WHICH RUNNING POSTGRESQL. I don't want someone write codes for me. I asked any queries exists for doing that job. thank you so much for your immediate answer :)

Comment: 'COPY' command but it only saves the the table. If I use this I will need to copy image fistly to database and then export it. it is not usefull.

Comment: In any case you need some software to make requests to the PostgreSQL. One of this is `psql`. You can use its `\copy` command instead of server-side `copy` to transfer local data to the server.

Comment: A query?  No, not really.  You seriously need wrapper -- C# would be perfect.  Seriously, post what relevant code you have, and we'll see what can be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `pg_file_write` function from the `adminpack` is close to what you want, but it only supports text. It won't write raw binary.

You'd probably need to make a modified copy of the adminpack extension with a binary-capable `pg_file_write`.

Note that `COPY` is not suitable for this. `COPY BINARY` writes a header that means the file won't be usable as an image.

I suggest doing the upload out-of-band, not over the PostgreSQL protocol. Use a file transfer protocol - FTP, SFTP, CIFS ("SMB") - or similar.

Comment: thank you so much.. This is the answer which I wanted